# Spoon connectivity issue to PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

Error message is thrown while connecting to database from Spoon.

1. Selected the View option that appears in the upper-left corner of the screen, right-clicked on the Database connections option, and selected New.
2. Under Connection Type, selected the postgresql database engine.
3. Filled in the Settings options and gave the connection a name by typing it in the Connection Name. All the credentials entered are valid but still I get the below error message:

   Error connecting to database [XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX ] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
   Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

   Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
   The connection attempt failed.

   org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
   Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

   Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
   The connection attempt failed.

   ```
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:466)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:364)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:335)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:325)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:80)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2734)
   at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:591)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:43)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:137)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
   at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:88)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.xul.KettleDialog.show(KettleDialog.java:55)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:116)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:60)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:474)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:461)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.newConnection(Spoon.java:8805)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:313)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:157)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:141)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem.access$100(JfaceMenuitem.java:43)
   at org.pentaho.ui.xul.jface.tags.JfaceMenuitem$1.run(JfaceMenuitem.java:106)
   at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
   at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:545)
   at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:490)
   at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:402)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1347)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7989)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9269)
   at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:662)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
   ```

   Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
   Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
   The connection attempt failed.

   ```
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:579)
   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:450)
   ... 55 more
   ```

   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:233)
       at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:144)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
       at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
       at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:410)
       at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:280)
       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
       at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:561)
       ... 56 more
   Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: PSY-STG-DB1 
       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
       at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.(PGStream.java:61)
       at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109)
       ... 67 more

   Hostname       : XXX-XXX-XXX
   Port           : 1111
   Database name  : XXX_XXX_XX

Please suggest me how do I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all check this:

- Server is up and running? (Postgres)
- Why port is 1111 instead of 5432
- Can you connect with pgadmin?

I think is a configuration problem